# Xtext - how to constrain a value to be in specific range?

Tags: eclipse, validation, range, dsl, xtext

I develop simple DSL language in Xtext, similar to JSON or markup language. I want to automatically validate entered integer values range while editing my custom language project. For example, I have attribute "timeout", and I want to give constraints from 100 to 1000. I know terminal rules, but it allows only to validate single number characters: from 0 to 9. Actually, I can write something like that:

```
terminal RANGE :
    ('0'..'9')('0'..'9')('0'..'9') | ('0'..'9')('0'..'9')('0'..'9')('0'..'9')
```

to express a certain amount of digits' numbers, but I don't think it is a clever solution.

Is there any possibility to make rules for such ranges?

Answer (score 0):

You can either registering a custom `IValueConverter` for your `RANGE` terminal rule through a binding `IValueConverterService` in guice.

Or you implement semantic validations at all places that use `RANGE` as attribute.

Comment: ValueConverter looks interesting. Is there any templates to create such binding?

Comment: Inside the tmf xtext forum there should be plenty and the default impl can deal as example as well